# Scope confusion in F#

Tags: scope, f#

Let's consider this code:

```
type TypeA = 
    {
        A : int
    }

type TypeB =
    {
        B : float
    }

module Test =
    let mutable c : TypeA = { A = 0 }

module Test2 =
    let mutable c : TypeB = { B = 0 }
```

it produces the error:

```
typecheck error This expression was expected to have type
    'float'    
but here has type
    'int'
```

What I do not understand is why there is a collision between the two variables *'c'*.

They have different scopes:

```
type TypeA = 
    {
        A : int
    }

module Test =
    let mutable c : TypeA = { A = 0 }

module Test2 =
    let mutable c : TypeA = { A = 0 }
```

with

```
Test.c <- { A = 1 }
Test2.c <- { A = 2 }
Test.c, Test2.c
```

gives

> { FSI_0009+TypeA: A: 1 }    { FSI_0009+TypeA: A: 2 }

Can someone explain why there is this error?

Comment: Question lacks a minimal example. If you had created a minimal example by removing type A and module Test and mutable then you would have written a different question or not needed to ask one at all.

Comment: @CharlesRoddie, it's a good point: If I had rewritten the code, I'd have seen the mistake in the first place. The funny part is that it was a rewrite from a piece of code that is really doing something and I managed to copy the mistake in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no collision between two variables `c` - they are defined in separate modules. F# just cannot implicitly convet integer literal `0` to float. Use `0.0` or `0.` in the second case:

```
let mutable c : TypeB = { B = 0.0 }
```

Also, F# type inference is smart enough to infer that the first variable `c` has type `TypeA`, and the second variable `c` has type `TypeB` (because record labels are different) so you can even remove type annotations here:

```
module Test =
    let mutable c = { A = 0 } // TypeA inferred

module Test2 =
    let mutable c = { B = 0. } // TypeB inferred
```